# SQLite3 request doesn't work because of ' character

Tags: python, sqlite

I created a python script to create a sqlite3 database with one table. This table is composed of 2 columns : one for the id (int) and the other for the associated sentence (text). Here is the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3

i=0
con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cur = con.cursor()  
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE data(data_id int, sentence text)''')  

with open("data.txt", "r") as ins:
        for line in ins:
        i = i + 1
        cur.execute("insert into data(data_id, sentence) values ("+str(i)+",'"+line+"')")

con.commit()
con.close()
```

As you can see, this code will read the file data.txt which is a file that contains sentences on each line.

When I try to execute the script, I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scriptData.py", line 13, in <module>
    cur.execute("insert into data(data_id, sentence) values ("+str(i)+",'"+line+"')")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "che": syntax error
```

This is due to the fact that in my file data.txt, some lines have the ' character which is a problem. I tried to protect this character by doing \' in my data.txt file but it didn't work. 
The problem is that I need to keep ' in my sentences. I'm not a python programmer so my knowledge is very limited. Do you have any idea to make this script work ?

Comment: _Do not concatenate data into queries; use query parameters!_ `cur.execute("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (?, ?)", (i, line))`

Comment: Otherwise someone might give you a sentence about their son Bobby..

Comment: To expand Chads comment: [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use escaping to prevent such situation when you pass params to SQL queries:

```
cur.execute("insert into data(data_id, sentence) values (?, ?)", (i, line))
```

Comment: I can never remember if sqlite supports `%s` styled formatting - it's more traditional to use `?`

Comment: I get an error : sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error.

Comment: @Mtoypc, sorry for that, I forgot that sqlite3 doesn't support % syntax, I've fixed answer.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I just had to add this : con.text_factory = str

Answer (score 3):

*Do not concatenate data into SQL queries.* Doing so is dangerous; malicious users can perform SQL injection attacks. Use query parameters instead.

```
cur.execute("insert into data(data_id, sentence) values (?, ?)", (i, line))
```

Also note that the query can be made more efficient by using `executemany` instead of a for loop:

```
cur.execute("insert into data(data_id, sentence) values (?, ?)", enumerate(ins))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I know that it is dangerous, but this script is just here to help me create the database. Nobody else than me will access to it.

Comment: @Mtoypc Well, not only is it safe, but the query will work for any text value of `line`, unlike simply concatenating it. Not to mention that query parameters are required if you use `executemany`, which is needed for performance if you're inserting a large amount of rows.